# node js compare mongodb database time and current time of a server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the code below updating offers_status to 'expired' if date stored on  a mongodb database is old than current system/server time;

```
dbo.collection("offers").updateMany({older_date_in_DB:{$lt: current_system_time},
     {$set: 
     {offerStatus:"EXPIRED"}},
     (err,response)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(response.modifiedCount)
    })
```

However, i notice that if the current date is say 10/18/2019 and older_date_in_db is say 08/01/2019,the query above doesn't update the offer status to 'EXPIRED'. I don't understand why? 
A date like 10/15/2019 updates the status to "EXPIRED" while a date like "08/01/2019" doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use following line for compare date condition in mongodb

```
 { older_date_in_DB: { $lt: new Date('10/18/2019') } }
```

if value is dateFormat then use new keyword